# Adjusting Widgets in a Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, widget, android-scrollview

Hey I have a ScrollView which allow users to input their credentials in the EditTexts inside. But there's one problem, one of the TextViews prior to its EditText consist of a Spinner but I do not know how to make that Spinner and the TextView side by side. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!:)

My xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="344dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView39"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Billing Address"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView38"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="First Name"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView40"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Last Name"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView41"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Street"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView42"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Country"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        android:layout_width="344dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView39"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Billing Address"
                android:textSize="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView38"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="First Name"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView40"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Last Name"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView41"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Street"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView42"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                    android:text="Country"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Linear Layout after Edittext3 as:

```
<!--Use dimensions of your choice-->
    <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          <!-- TO display in center use android:layout_gravity="center" -->
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView42"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Country"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </LinearLayout>
```